# obtener el valor que selecciono de mis SELECT con JavaScript, PHP, Ajax o JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, aplicación-web

necesito obtener el valor de mis select, obtener el valor texto, ya que cuando lo obtengo solo me sale el ID, y la verdad no se como hacerlo. quiero que al darle a al boton y ya que haya llenado mi select me lo muestre en otra pagina.

este es mi index, donde tengo mis select

```
<form action="" method="">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Marca</label>
      <select name="marca" id="marca" class="form-control" 
       onchange="FetchModelo(this.value)" required>
        <option value="">Seleccionar Marca</option>
      <?php
        if ($result->num_rows > 0 ) {
           while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<option value='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['nom_marca'].'</option>';
           }
        }
      ?> 
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Modelo</label>
      <select name="modelo" id="modelo" class="form-control" 
      onchange="FetchAnio(this.value)" required>
        <option>Selecciona Modelo</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Año</label>
      <select name="anio" id="anio" class="form-control">
        <option>Selecciona el Año</option>
      </select>
    </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar datos!">
</form>
```

este es mi script de ajax que tengo en mi index aqui muestro mi select llenado ya que mando a llamar un php que tengo donde mando todo lo de mis tablas

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function FetchModelo(id){
$('#modelo').html('');
$('#anio').html('<option>Elige Año</option>');
$.ajax({
  type:'post',
  url: 'ajaxdata.php',
  data : { id_marca : id},
  success : function(data){
     $('#modelo').html(data);
  }

})
}

function FetchAnio(id){ 
$('#anio').html('');
$.ajax({
  type:'post',
  url: 'ajaxdata.php',
  data : { id_modelo : id},
  success : function(data){
     $('#anio').html(data);
  }

})
}
```

tengo un php llamado ajaxdata.php donde obtengo todo lo de mi base de datos. y tambien con option value hago que lo muetre el texto pero me manda el id de mi base de datos.

```
<?php 
   include_once 'config.php';

  if (isset($_POST['id_marca'])) {
   $query = "SELECT * FROM modelo where id_delamarca=".$_POST['id_marca'];
   $result = $db->query($query);
   if ($result->num_rows > 0 ) {
        echo '<option value="">Elige el Modelo</option>';
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['nom_modelo'].'</option>';
     }
  }else{

    echo '<option>Modelo no encontrado</option>';
  }

 }elseif (isset($_POST['id_modelo'])) {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM anio where id_delmodelo=".$_POST['id_modelo'];
  $result = $db->query($query);
   if ($result->num_rows > 0 ) {
        echo '<option value="">Elige el Año</option>';
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['num_anio'].'</option>';
     }
 }else{

    echo '<option>Año no encontrado</option>';
  }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el texto del select usas el método val() de jQuery, pero solo funciona si no tienes un atributo value="" en tu etiqueta option dentro de tu select

Sacas primero el value, lo pones en una variable y luego le dices con un simple selector que te encuentr5e de que elementos se esta hablando y le dices a jquery que te de su propiedad text() y obtienes el texto del elementos option.

```
<script>
    var value_select_marca = $('#marca').val() 
    $('#marca > option[value='+value_select_marca+']').text()
</script>
```